# Point subdomain to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname, vercel

I bought a domain with Google. I set up custom name servers to point the domain to Zeit.

**Custom Name Servers**

- f.zeit-world.net
- d.zeit-world.com
- b.zeit-world.org
- a.zeit-world.co.uk

Zeit controls the domain. I have spun up an EC2 instance with an elastic IP. I want to be able to point api.mydomain.com to the elastic IP using a CNAME.

*added fake elastic ip just for example*
`now dns add mydomain.com api CNAME 194.119.279.121`

I am not sure why it's not being resolved, obviously, I am missing some information. The URL api.mydomain.com just hangs.

Any insight into what step I am missing?

Comment: Some things to check - Does the Security Group on your EC2 instance allow HTTP traffic from the internet? Is the subnet that your EC2 instance is deployed into associated to a VPC Route Table with a Route to an Internet Gateway? Can you reach the EC2 instance by hitting the IP address?

Comment: Did you try to do "dig CNAME +short api.mydomain.com"?

Comment: I would say you need `A` record for the IP, not CNAME.

Comment: Updated A records `api A ELASTIC_IP` about to check the security group. HTTP traffic should be allowed as I have successfully made http requests to the elastic IP.

Comment: Ahh I think I know what it is. The instance is serving up via node.js on port 4000. I need to setup nginx to proxy :4000 to :80